# Running Newer Ruby Version Next to Existing Ruby Version

Tags: ruby, openssl

DISCLOSURE: I know very little about Ruby beyond some basic code syntax. Bear with my idiocy.

Ruby 1.8's OpenSSL library doesn't seem to support TLS 1.2. However, there are apps running that are dependent on 1.8, so I want to see if I can run a newer version of Ruby concurrently on the same system and get it set up with newer versions of the same gems.

Currently version 1.8 is at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8. Ideally, I'd like to keep the same structure and install a newer version (not sure what the most recent, stable version is - whether it's 2.3.x or 2.4.x).

That said, I am not a Ruby admin. I inherited a server from someone else who decided Ruby was the best way to do things, despite there being no other Ruby experience within the company, and then they left. I know some system admin stuff, but I don't know:

1. How backwards-compatible Ruby versions are (e.g. would an app built against 1.8 run without any major modifications on 2.4.1).
2. How gems work / get updated. Can 2.4.1 use gems from 1.8, or are gems tied to specific Ruby versions? Can there be a mix-and-match? Is there a migration path of some kind?
3. How to properly manage two different concurrent versions (how to tell an app to use one version over the other, or prevent existing apps from automatically trying to use the new version and breaking if they're not compatible).
4. Any best install practices (I usually compile from source, but am open to suggestions).
5. Is it even possible to just update Ruby's OpenSSL library without updating the whole Ruby app? It's currently on OpenSSL 0.9.8o, so it's pretty significantly behind the times.

The server is running Debian 6.0.6 (I'm more familiar with Red Hat and CentOS, though, so any hints on package management, etc... related to this issue would be welcomed).

Answer (score 4):

1. Modern ruby has "matured" and become very stable. Upgrading from `2.0.0` --> (the latest stable) `2.4.1` is generally quite easy. However, ruby went through a period of fairly major (necessary!) changes from `1.8` --> `1.9` --> `2.0`; this part of the upgrade may be problematic.
2. Gems are installed within the current ruby installation. So for example, you currently have the "ruby 1.8 version" of `CanCan`. If you update the ruby version of this application, you will need to re-install all gems (presumably via `bundle install`) for the ruby version. The migration path is basically: Get as comprehensive a test suite as possible; upgrade gems as much as possible within that ruby version; update the ruby version; fix tests and/or code if necessary; repeat.
3. Use a tool like `rvm` or `rbenv` to install multiple concurrent ruby versions on one machine.
4. See point 3. You probably don't need to compile anything from source.
5. Ruby 1.8 is *old*. Support for it was dropped back in 2013. Your application will undoubtedly have a huge list of outdated libraries now, with all sorts of security vulnerabilities -- that's what happens when you don't update it for 6+ years! From a security standpoint, I would not suggest trying to find some workaround for this one OpenSSL issue and ignore the larger problem here.

Comment: So apparently the system's own OpenSSL library was still back on 0.9.8o. Ugh. So it's obvious the system needs a bigger overhaul - but that's going to be a much larger process, and I'm just trying to find an interim fix to resolve a showstopping problem for our developers. 

I'm installing OpenSSL 1.0.2l into a separate folder /usr/local/openssl/1.0.2l on the system. Any chance there's a way to update the existing Ruby install to simply point to that?

Comment: I don't have "rvm" or "rbenv" installed, apparently.

Comment: OpenSSLs ABI has also changed between 0.9.8 and 1.0.2. Thus, your already compiled Ruby 1.8 probably won't work (correctly) with an OpenSSL 1.0.2 without a recompile.

Comment: You would need to re-compile ruby from source, and after a quick google, possibly apply some [patch](https://gist.github.com/hyoshida/11241844)(es)? I've never attempted this before, so I don't know for sure. but as I say, you undoubtedly have a myriad of other security issues to deal with also; a long term fix is definitely to upgrade properly or rewrite it all.